# Restore prototype methods after postMessage()

Tags: javascript, prototype, web-worker

**I have the following JavaScript object:**

```
function Node() {
    this.id       = 0;
    this.parent   = null;
    this.children = [];
}
Node.prototype.toString = function() {
    return "ID: " + this.id;
};
```

**This is an example how it can be used:**

```
var node = new Node();
node.id = 1;
node.parent = new Node();
parent.children.push(node);
node.toString();         // returns "ID: 1"
```

**Now I have the following problem:**

The above example code is executed in a web worker - so the nodes are created there. Afterwards, I use [`postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to send the node to the main thread.

JavaScript automatically creates a deep copy of the object. But - of course - when doing so, it creates a plain JavaScript object, not an object that inherits it's properties from `Node`. Therefore, the `toString()` function cannot be called within the main thread.

What is the easiest and most performant way to restore the nodes, such that my prototype-methods are available again? This should be done in the main thread after I received the object from the web worker.

Ideally, it should be done without creating another copy of the data, as it can potentially contain a lot of nodes and also has cycles.

My workaround would be to give up on prototype-methods and instead pass nodes as an argument to a free function. But that's not a nice thing to do.

Comment: Why not just add prototype fns as normal fns in the Object, like this.toString = () => 'ID: ' + this.id; in Node? And then Name the functions properly instead like this.getNodeId = () => 'ID: ' + this.id;

Comment: Adding the functions directly to the objects via `this.toString = ...` does not work, because `postMessage()` will fail to copy/serialize it. And the `toString()` just serves as an example. The actual implementation is more complex.

Comment: that is true, it does not serialize functions, you just have to create does fns afterwards and add them to the received Node.

Comment: Yes, that would be a possible option. The downside is, that all transfered nodes will get one additional property per prototype-method. If there are a lot of such nodes, and there are also a few of those methods, this approach creates a lot of members (possibly affecting memory pretty bad). But I guess it's the only alternative if you can't modify an existing prototype-chain.

Comment: Ok, nevermind. I'm feeling stupid. Overwriting the prototype chain of course works (`receivedNode.__proto__.toString = ...`), but leads to more or less the exact same result as your suggestion. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it and you get your reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your protos afterwards and add them to the received node like:

```
let proto = node => { return {toString: () => 'ID: ' + node.id}}
let node = new Node();
node = Object.assign(node, proto(node));
```

Comment: did this help @maja

Comment: I still don't like the idea of iterating all nodes and manually applying the prototype-methods. The iteration requires a lot of time, and the browser cannot do much optimization when calling the functions later. But your approach, at least, does not require to make a full copy of every node and also works with nested/recursive node objects.
I changed my code to not use prototype-methods at all, but if this is not an option for someone, your solution is propably the best one.